# Using UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight to flip over a UIButton when pressed and show a new button on "the other side"

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

EDITED For MOXY.

I have an array of buttons with an image on top and array of buttons whose views are background colors. When i click on a button i want to retrieve that button index and use that index to also get the appropriate background color of the other view..and use that information to flip the button(with the image) and "turn it over" to reveal the background color.

The make up of my screen is, ViewControllersView->TileView->(array of buttons).

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 _viewContents = [model getRequestedView];  //this retrieves an array of UIButtons(24 
  //of them) whose frames and background colors have already been initialized to fit
   //within the TileView.
 _viewFrontImageContents =[model getRequestedViewFrontCardImagesWithFrame:_viewContents];

for(int screenViewIndex = 0; screenViewIndex < [_viewContents count]; screenViewIndex++){
    [TileView addSubview:[_viewFrontImageContents objectAtIndex:screenViewIndex]];
    [[_viewFrontImageContents objectAtIndex:screenViewIndex] addTarget:self action:@selector(frontOfCardPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[TileView addSubview:[_viewContents objectAtIndex:screenViewIndex]];
    //[[_viewContents objectAtIndex:screenViewIndex] addTarget:self action:@selector(frontOfCardPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

}
```

//getRequestedViewFrontCardImagesWithFrame method

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getRequestedViewFrontCardImagesWithFrame:(NSArray *)views{
        NSMutableArray *cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        UIImage *frontOfCardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_of_Tile"];
        UIButton *frontOfCardView;

        for(int viewIndex = 0; viewIndex < [views count]; viewIndex++){
            frontOfCardView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:[[views objectAtIndex:viewIndex] frame]];
            frontOfCardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:frontOfCardImage];
  //setting the tag of each frontCard to match the view index to keep them aligned.
            frontOfCardView.tag = viewIndex;
            [cards addObject:frontOfCardView];

            if(viewIndex == 0){
              NSLog(@"first frontcard frame %@, first _viewContentsFrame %@", [cards objectAtIndex:0], [views objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

Above I am adding UIButtons with an image on top to represent the "front of a playing card". The indices of said buttons matches exactly the indeces of the _viewContents array.I set up each button to match the frame(size and location) of the buttons that have been initialized already.

```
-(IBAction)frontOfCardPushed:(id)sender{
int containerViewIndex = -1;
UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"Button Index: %i", pressedButton.tag);
containerViewIndex = pressedButton.tag;
UIView *container = [TileView viewWithTag:containerViewIndex];
UIView *viewToShow = [_viewContents objectAtIndex:containerViewIndex];
NSLog(@"container: %@, viewToShow: %@", container, viewToShow);
//viewToShow.frame = container.frame;
//NSLog(@"container: %@, viewToShow: %@", container, viewToShow);

[UIView transitionWithView:container duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    [sender removeFromSuperview];
                    [container addSubview:viewToShow];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

what I want to do is use a transition - namely 'UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight' to"flip the card" when pressed to reveal the contents of the associated _viewContents array. I also want to be able for the user to flip the card back over to reveal the image of the frontCardButton. This piece of code above just focuses on the first flip of the card to avoid a wall of code.

I am seeing the appropriate background colors - but the animation itself is not working.

What am i doing wrong and what do I need to add/remove to this piece of code to make it work?

- EDIT* 
  As noted below to Moxy, take a look at the output of whats in the getRequestedViewFrontCardImagesWithFrame method. Look at the output of the first card and then look at the output of the container view in the frontCardPushed: method after requesting the view with the appropriate tag - they do no match. I am printing out the button index so that you can see I am hitting the first TileView subview. The tag of the _viewContents view is a tag set the represents a color and has nothing to do with the TileView tag that I assign in the getRequestedViewFrontCardImagesWithFrame method. It is puzzling however that right after i assign a tag to the first button when i print it out, a tag isnt listed.

OUTPUT:

```
//why doesnt the first frontcard frame list a tag? I had just assigned it one?
```

> first frontcard frame UIButton: 0x1c53f020; frame = (6 5; 145 145);
>   opaque = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x1c534ac0, first _viewContentsFrame
>   UIButton: 0x1d045220; frame = (6 5; 145 145); opaque = NO; tag = 3;
>   layer = CALayer: 0x1d04535
>
> Button Index: 0
>   container: UIView: 0x1c53a400; frame = (51 83; 922
>   614); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers =
>   NSArray: 0x1d05afe0>; layer = CALayer: 0x1c53a460, viewToShow:
>   UIButton: 0x1d045220; frame = (6 5; 145 145); opaque = NO; tag = 3;
>   layer = CALayer: 0x1d045350

Comment: -addSubview: is not animatable. Try to use the buttons state, instead of using other views.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion:  - check out this from apple.(this may not get you right to the transitionWithView method). I am basically doing the same thing here. Quote from this method: The following code creates a flip transition for the specified container view...."

Comment: My comment is in a way out of context, as +transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion: animate the flipping of the container view and not the fact of adding the subview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it work by using a container view to hold the buttons.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _viewContents = [model getRequestedView];  //this retrieves an array of UIButtons(24 of them) whose frames and background colors have already been initialized to fit within the TileView.

    for(int i = 0; i < [_viewContents count]; i++){
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[_viewContents objectAtIndex:screenViewIndex] frame]]; 
        container.tag = i;      
        UIButton *frontOfCardView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:container.bounds];
        frontOfCardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:_frontOfCardImage];
        frontOfCardView.tag = i;
        [container addSubview:frontOfCardView]; 
        [frontOfCardView addTarget:self action:@selector(frontOfCardPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [tileView addSubview:container];
    }
}

-(IBAction)frontOfCardPushed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIView *container = [tileView viewWithTag:sender.tag];
    UIView *viewToShow = [_viewContents objectAtIndex:index];
    viewToShow.frame = sender.frame;
    [UIView transitionWithView:container
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                      [sender removeFromSuperView];
                      [container addSubview:viewToShow];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. Anyway, this is not very clean/pretty code. But, I understand it's only for learning purpose.

Let me know if it still doesn't work.

EDIT :

I made a simple project with a single view controller as an example. I think that the way you keep track of all your views/buttons is useless. In this case the model is only a background color and all you want to do is to reveal/hide it, so once you assign the color to a button, all it has to know is to switch states, so you don't even need tags.(In other cases the controller would need to identify which button that received an event in order to ask the model what content it needs)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *colors;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *tileView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma Getters and setters

// I'm assuming the tileView is just a simple view to wrap all the buttons
// PS : propertys should always start with a lowercase letter
-(UIView *)tileView
{
    if (!_tileView) {
        _tileView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        _tileView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return _tileView;
}

// The model: just an array of colors, you can generate it or use other complicated stuff
-(NSArray *)colors
{
    if (!_colors) {
        _colors = @[[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor grayColor], [UIColor yellowColor],
                    [UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                    [UIColor lightGrayColor], [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor magentaColor],
                    [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor grayColor], [UIColor yellowColor],
                    [UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor darkGrayColor],
                    [UIColor lightGrayColor], [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor magentaColor]];
    }
    return _colors;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Helper methods

#define ROWS 6
#define COLUMNS 4
#define CARD_HEIGHT 60.0f
#define CARD_WIDTH 40.0f

// Gets the width that each card can use based on the chose number of columns
-(CGFloat)horizontalStep
{
    return self.tileView.frame.size.width / COLUMNS;
}

// Gets the height that each card can use based on the chose number of columns
-(CGFloat)verticalStep
{
    return self.tileView.frame.size.height / ROWS;
}

// Calculates the center for the card frame (return (0,0) if the index is out of bounds)
-(CGPoint)centerForCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CGFloat x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f;
    if (index < [self.colors count]) {
        x = [self horizontalStep] * 0.5f + (index % COLUMNS) * [self horizontalStep];
        y = [self verticalStep] * 0.5f + (index / COLUMNS) * [self verticalStep];
    }
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

// Gets the frame for the card at index
-(CGRect)frameForCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CGPoint center = [self centerForCardAtIndex:index];
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(center.x - CARD_WIDTH * 0.5f, center.y - CARD_HEIGHT * 0.5f);
    return CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
}

-(void)layoutCards
{
    // Add tileView to the controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:self.tileView];
    // Create the card buttons and add them to the tile view
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.colors count]; i++) {
        UIButton *card = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        card.frame = [self frameForCardAtIndex:i];

        // The only use of the model IN THIS CASE
        card.backgroundColor = self.colors[i];
        [card setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_of_tile.png"]
              forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [card addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(cardPressed:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.tileView addSubview:card];
    }
}

-(void)cardPressed:(UIButton *)card
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:card
                      duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:^{
                        card.selected = !card.selected;
                        if (!card.selected) {
                            [card setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_of_tile.png"]
                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        } else {
                            [card setImage:nil
                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self layoutCards];
}
```

Comment: ok i am going to test later this evening then get back to you with another comment - thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Moxy - i have edited my code above and added a code snippet so you can get a better scope of what is going on. For some reason the container UIView frame settings are getting messed up. In my updated code you can see the output of just what I am talking about. besides this, the WHOLE view TileView(which is a subview of the controllers view set up in IB) flips, not just the subview that i clicked on. Strange behavior. Let me know what you think

Comment: please note the new method that i placed in there. you will see that i am already assigning the frame to the _viewcontents frame that i already loaded in from the previous call. I am doing this ahead of time to make sure that the frontCardButtons are already aligned with the _viewContents UIButtons. Please refer to my output to see that when i press the first button(index 0) the frame of that button seems to be wacky and offset in the x,y origin. This is puzzling. If you want to talk further let me know so we can talk via IM or whatever. thanks again for the help.

Comment: Moxy - thanks for the edited code. The scope of this app is a matching card app with many screens and each screen having a set of 24 tiles. the tiles can have things other than just background colors. they can have images and even custom QUartz 2D graphics behind them. Each time the app runs those contents are randomized across multiple screens. The TileView is a subview of the main view controllers view and is defined in IB. and right now i am using a swipe gesture to animate in a new set of tiles that may not have a match on that particular screen.

Comment: continued - every time i get a new screen(after i swipe and one animates in - i have to populate it) -  i have to go out to the model and retrieve the contents of that screen(the code for swiping and getting the new contents not shown in this thread). If i have had a match in the past then the model has been updated for this so that when you swipe back to the screen later you won't have any button to press. So no, the model is not only background colors. It has all the contents for all the buttons that are going to be on each screen(TileView - which is a subview on the controllers view).

Comment: continues - i am going to look at wehat you have here and add some additional checks in the animation block like you have. The only difference is that i have to pre-build the first set of tileviews so that i see the front of the card (the image) when the app first starts. Let me know if you have any questions/comments/thoughts. ill update you on what i come up with -"(In other cases the controller would need to identify which button that received an event in order to ask the model what content it needs)" this is pretty much the case that I am at now.

Comment: I know about Paul Hegarty's assignment. The question was about the transition animation... so maybe discussing a whole project will make it confusing here. If you want we can use the chat and discuss it.

Comment: well ironically this isnt that assignment - although this could resemble it a lot - havent been following the courses on iTunes. Please lets chat..can u invite? i dont see anyway to invite a single user.

Comment: To everyone else - Moxy was way more than helpful. Kudos. Deserve 1000 upvotes

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to do this would be to use [UIView transitionWithView]:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.flipButton
                  duration:0.8
                   options:displayingFirstButton ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                  //change image for button
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
```